# Amazon S3 multipart uploads with progress bar using PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How do I get the progress of a multipart uploader?

This is what I have and the progress callback is never called. Is it possible to get progress through the PHP SDK?

```
$uploader = new MultipartUploader($s3Client, $uploadedFile->getRealPath(), [
    'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
    'key' => $filename,
    '@http' => [
        'progress' => function ($expectedDl, $dl, $expectedUl, $ul) {
            // This never gets called
        }
    ]
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution on my own. You pass a "params" key in the configuration array parameter containing the @http progress event callback.

> params: (array) An array of key/value parameters that will be applied
>   to each of the sub-commands run by the uploader as a base.

```
$uploader = new MultipartUploader($s3Client, $uploadedFile->getRealPath(), [
    'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
    'key' => $filename,
    'params' => [
        '@http' => [
            'progress' => function ($expectedDl, $dl, $expectedUl, $ul) {
                // This gets called
            }
        ]
    ]
]);
```

First try was close, but I wish this feature was more visible in guides as progress bars are a common UI element.

Comment: Inside the progress function, how do you update the UI? Maybe with realtime notifications via Pusher?